# Animate item creation on Bootstrap List group

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I use Bootstrap's list group to display a list of item like this :

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Aucune catégorie</li>
        <div class="newitems"></div><br/>
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="text" placeholder="New item" class="newcat form-control"/></li>
</ul>
```

And this little piece of jQuery to add items :

```
$('.newcat').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    $('.newitems').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + $(this).val() + '</li>');
});

$('.newcat').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
```

It works juste fine, but I'd like to add an animation to make it better. I tried the `slideDown` method, that's in theory what I'd want, but it's not working when applied to the `append()` method. 
How can I make this move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object and then use the `appendTo` method instead of the `append`:

```
$('.newcat').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    $('<li class="list-group-item">' + this.value + '</li>')
        .hide()
        .appendTo('.newitems')
        .slideDown(); // collection contains the newly created element

    this.value = '';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VzHFW/